# Why can't Acumatica find a view?

Tags: acumatica

I created a DAC extension mapped to an extension table off of SOShipment. I have two custom fields in the extension table that I'd like to add to the Sales Orders entry form, specifically the grid in the Shipments tab. When I go to the layout editor for this form and select the Grid: ShipmentList under the Shipments tab, there are no fields in the Add Data Fields tab on the right. Also, I see a yellow circle with this error in several places:

> The "ShipmentList" view is not found. Try to publish the customization project.

I published the customization project, but the error persists. To my knowledge, we haven't done any customization that would've touched the ShipmentList view. What is the issue here and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a case sensitivity  issue ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9SKE.png

Comment: I don't believe so. We haven't referenced that list in our customizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to add those Custom fields to the Grid: ShipmentList(which primary DAC is SOOrderShipment), make sure you add the Custom Fields to the Correct DAC extension, the correct DAC extension should be for **SOOrderShipment**.

(You have to rename the DataView because in **base code**, this Dataview is named **shipmentList**. However, the editor Tool when generating Customization Script for that screen is assigning **ShipmentList**(Capital S) to Datamember instead of correct Dataview name. )

So, then Go to Section Screen, Select SO301000 screen, select the Grid(ShipmentList) under the Shipments Tab, select Action->Edit ASPX, then locate on *DataMember="ShipmentList"* (with Capital S) and replace it for *DataMember="shipmentList"* (lowercase s). Then click on "**Generate Customization Script**" and **publish** your Customization.

[image]

After publishing, go to SO30100 Screen, select correct Grid and you will  be able to see new Custom Fields and the warning message gone.

[image]