# Unable to expand Shipments detail entity using SalesOrder REST API endpoint

Tags: acumatica

I'm seeing a strange behavior using Acumatica's default endpoints. Specifically, I'm trying to expand the Shipments detail entity of the default SalesOrder endpoint.

My `GET` URI looks like:

`/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/00005147?$expand=Shipments`

The sales order is found and other detail entities are expanded (if I explicitly specify them), but the response for Shipments always returns an empty array even when I'm retrieving Sales Orders which have associated shipments.

```
... clip ...
"RequestedOn": {
    "value": "2018-04-03T00:00:00+00:00"
},
"Shipments": [], <-- this is always empty, even when there are shipments
"ShipToAddressOverride": {
    "value": true
},
...
```

This detail entity is also empty when looking at the raw schema, whereas the other detail entities like `BillToAddress` and `FinancialSettings` are expanded.

`/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/$adHocSchema`

My Acumatica version is: Acumatica 2017 R2 Build 17.203.0029.

Any ideas how to expand the Shipments detail entity? I need to retrieve related ShipmentNbrs so I can subsequently find carrier tracking numbers.

I'm wondering the problem is related to this issue described on StackOverflow whereby the ShipmentList DataView doesn't have the correct spelling?

[Why can't Acumatica find a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415852/why-cant-acumatica-find-a-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a custom field to the Shipments tab grid on the Sales Order entry screen, I had to rename the view to "shipmentlist". (See linked post in original question.) This customization was causing the empty endpoint detail entity. Renaming it back to "ShipmentList" after adding the custom column solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried against my local 17.203.0029 instance and was able to get the Shipments expanded for a sales order using this as my URL, the only difference from yours is the OrderNbr.

```
entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/100225?$expand=Shipments
```

Can you try repairing your database? Doing so will re-build the Default endpoint that Acumatica provides, I'm guessing that maybe there is something wrong with yours which I have seen happen before.

To repair

1. Open the Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard
2. Go to Perform Database Maintenance
3. When you get to the part where you can create or select an existing database, select your existing database and check the box on the right that says Repair database. After you click finish it will take a few minutes but it will delete and re-create the Default endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: These steps did not solve the problem, but thank you very much for your help. By verifying it worked for you I was able to track down the issue. A custom grid column in the ShipmentList view was causing the problem. Sorry for the false alarm.