# ShipmentList View in Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I have tried remaining the DataMember name from capital "S" (ShipmentList) to lower-case "s" (shipmentList), but still not solved. Below link I referred before posting here but that not solved my issue, also, have a look at screenshot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433472/4878854

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `shipmentlist` as a DataMember and not `shipmentList`.
If you open `PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry` BLC/graph you can find the following dataview:

```
public PXSelectJoin<SOOrderShipment, LeftJoin<SOShipment, On<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>, And<SOShipment.shipmentType, Equal<SOOrderShipment.shipmentType>>>>,Where<SOOrderShipment.orderType, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderType>>, And<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>> shipmentlist;
```