# Shipping address in invoice screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to show the shipping address from Shipments screen in Invoice screen. As we don't have a shipping address in Invoice screen, i have created a view (bql) and form view in .aspx page in the header section of invoice screen.

The problem is, the address is not displaying when page loads but it is getting populated when I do Inspect Element on address line 1 field. What might be the issue? Here is my code:

```
public PXSelect<SOAddress, Where<SOAddress.addressID, Equal<Current<SOInvoice.shipAddressID>>>> ShipToAddress;

<px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="PXFormView2" AllowCollapse="false" Caption="Ship To" RenderStyle="Fieldset" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="ShipToAddress">
            <Template>
                <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" Enabled="false" DataField="AddressLine1" ID="edAddressLine1" />
            </Template>
        </px:PXFormView>
```

Comment: I believe issue is with fetching the current object. Inspect Element doesn't help for me, however I noticed that going to Shipment screen Orders Tab and clicking on Invoice link then it will show up on invoice page.

Answer (score 0):

SOInvoice Current object doesn't load reliably in Invoice screen.

This is likely due to SOInvoice being a child of ARInvoice.

ARInvoice Current object will load reliably so we can use that in the DataView instead of SOInvoice Current:

```
  PXSelectJoin<SOShipmentAddress, 
  InnerJoin<SOInvoice, On<SOInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Current<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>,
  Where<SOShipmentAddress.addressID, Equal<SOInvoice.shipAddressID>>> ShipToAddress;
```

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, thank you for inputs and sorry for late reply, i used the code snippet but am facing "ShipToAddress" view not found issue.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at T100 on how to work with DataView.  You already had a ShipToAddress view, I suggested you modify it. Modifying the view will not lead to the 'view not found issue'. This is a basic error, you likely made an error in deploying the project. Can you rollback to the previous state where the view was found?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415852/why-cant-acumatica-find-a-view